# CakePHP update many to many resource

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a category-product many to many relationship. When a product is created one or more categories are selected and then the product is saved. This works fine and the join table is correctly populated. The issue is when I go to edit the product, I can add more categories, change them etc... The issue comes when I try to save, it fails.

The line that I'm using to save is:

```
$this->Product->saveAll($this->data)
```

$this->Product->id is correctly populated and the debug of $this->data gives me an array like so :

```
Array(

    [Product] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17
    )

    [Category] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 85
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 96
            )

    )

)
```

I don't know why it doesn't save as I can't find any detail on the error anywhere.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As raultm says, the structure was slightly wrong but it turned out to be validation in the model. The name and description fields were set to not allow empty and in the structure I wasn't passing these in (wasn't aware you had to on an update). By adding in the missing fields and naming the fields correctly in the array i.e. id, name and description, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think is this structure is wrong. If you are editing, where's the 'id' field of the product?

```
[Product] => Array
(
    [id] => 17
)
```

I do that in an application. I will check it out tomorrow(today I cant view the source), but i think the id is the problem.

Comment: Cheers, you're right the structure was wrong but it was also down to validation.